# change splash with image from ws

Tags: iphone

I am very new in iphone, and I need to set splash screen with image that comes after first enter from web service.
How and where to locate it?
How to set the new splash image as the splash screen?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't, the "splash screen" is called `Default.png` ans is stored in the application bundle.
The application bundle is read only and can not be modified.

You can add an extra splash screen after the application is start, but this then you will have to delay the starting of you app, which Apple is not to keep about.